# How to set object in a Play framework session or how to retrieve the current size transferred in aws?

Tags: amazon-s3, playframework

There is an upload object which will be returned by AWS on file upload. Where the upload object contains the byte transferred so far.

1. How to inject an object in play framework session ? So that it can be retrieved in the next ajax call to get the status of the file upload
2. Is there a way to get the byte transferred by AWS API by giving the file access key or file unique key in the next ajax call after file upload.

Thanks.

Comment: Any comments on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Play's session doesn't work this way : It's based ok cookies, and there is no storage out of the box (everything you set in a user's session end up in the a cookie), so you need to handle that yourself.
I would set a random UUID as session ID, and use a backend storage that storage a data blob based on a  combination.

2) Sure, but you need to hande that yourself. AWS's API is async, so you get an ID on upload, and use that later on to see the status,